# How to only include data into an array inside a foreach if it's unique?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a function that returns random fruit data. I want to return 5 different fruits every time, there shouldn't be the same values more than once.

Here is the example with the occurring problem I'm facing https://eval.in/957206 (it generate banana twice) and below is the code written.

```
function generateFruit(){
  $data = array(
      0 => array( 'id' => 1, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Banana')),
      1 => array( 'id' => 2, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Strawberry')),
      2 => array( 'id' => 3, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Orange')),
      3 => array( 'id' => 4, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Kiwi')),
      4 => array( 'id' => 5, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Apple')),
      5 => array( 'id' => 6, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Apricots')),
      6 => array( 'id' => 7, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Avacado')),
      7 => array( 'id' => 8, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Blueberries')),
      8 => array( 'id' => 9, 'fruit' => array( 'title' => 'Cranberries')),
      9 => array( 'id' => 10, 'fruit' => array( 'title' => 'Figs')),
      10 => array( 'id' => 11, 'fruit' => array( 'title' => 'Grapes')),
  );

  return $data[array_rand($data)];
}

function generateAllFruits(){
    foreach(range(1, 5) as $key => $useless){
        $data[$key] = array(
            'fruits' => generateFruit()
        );
    }

    print_r($data);
}

generateAllFruits();
```

I cannot use [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique) as that'll remove the duplicates instead of running the generateFruit code again and returning a new value that isn't in the `$data` array.

I could use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) , however it being a multidimensional array, it will not work without `column_array` as the second parameter, at least that's a way I could think of making it work, except.. it didn't.

Comment: Misread and had a bad answer, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shuffle` (randomize) the array and then pick the first 5:

```
shuffle($data);
$result = array_slice($data, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the `generateAllFruits` function instead of shuffling and returning it in the first function? It's totally my fault, I should have asked/mentioned that in the question itself, I'm sorry.

Comment: Then just add the code in the function and replace $result with return

Comment: The code you had updated 4 minutes ago was more of what I was looking for, I took a look then you updated it to the current (thought you had updated it).

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach. I returned the array so that I can modify and remove elements from the array like so:

```
function getFreshFruits() {
  return array(
    0 => array( 'id' => 1, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Banana')),
    1 => array( 'id' => 2, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Strawberry')),
    2 => array( 'id' => 3, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Orange')),
    3 => array( 'id' => 4, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Kiwi')),
    4 => array( 'id' => 5, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Apple')),
    5 => array( 'id' => 6, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Apricots')),
    6 => array( 'id' => 7, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Avacado')),
    7 => array( 'id' => 8, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Blueberries')),
    8 => array( 'id' => 9, 'fruit' => array( 'title' => 'Cranberries')),
    9 => array( 'id' => 10, 'fruit' => array( 'title' => 'Figs')),
    10 => array( 'id' => 11, 'fruit' => array( 'title' => 'Grapes')),
  );
}
```

After that, it's easy.

```
$freshFruits = getFreshFruits();
$pickedFruits = array();

$i = 0;
while ($i < 5) {
  $rando = rand(0,count($freshFruits)-1);
  array_push($pickedFruits,$freshFruits[$rando]);
  array_splice($freshFruits,$rando,1);
  $i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($pickedFruits);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [fruit] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Orange
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [fruit] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Apricots
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [fruit] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Apple
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [fruit] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Cranberries
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [fruit] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Avacado
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `array_rand` function you should use it with a second argument (number of returned values) as shown below.

```
$alldata = array(
  0 => array( 'id' => 1, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Banana')),
  1 => array( 'id' => 2, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Strawberry')),
  2 => array( 'id' => 3, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Orange')),
  3 => array( 'id' => 4, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Kiwi')),
  4 => array( 'id' => 5, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Apple')),
  5 => array( 'id' => 6, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Apricots')),
  6 => array( 'id' => 7, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Avacado')),
  7 => array( 'id' => 8, 'fruit' => array('title' => 'Blueberries')),
  8 => array( 'id' => 9, 'fruit' => array( 'title' => 'Cranberries')),
  9 => array( 'id' => 10, 'fruit' => array( 'title' => 'Figs')),
  10 => array( 'id' => 11, 'fruit' => array( 'title' => 'Grapes')),
);

foreach (array_rand($alldata,5) as $k => $v) $data[$k][fruits]=$alldata[$v];
print_r($data);
```

See here: https://eval.in/957212 . There is no need for your two functions.